# Setting bouncing curve in graph editor

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes, graph-editor

Is it possible to modify the **bouncing** and **elatic** curves in the graph editor ?

[image]

For example, **modifying the number of bounces**, **the amplitude**, ... ?

Comment: The amplitude can be changed with an envelope modifier, or by moving the second keyframe.

Comment: @batFINGER can you point to any examples of using an envelope modifier  to change the amplitude of a "bounce" or how to create a custom bounce using envelope modifiers?

Comment: Would this help?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109883/object-wont-drop-after-keyframing-animate-physics/112869#112869

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not much.

The amplitude is simply whatever time you let between the two keyframes. But you can't edit anything else.

I'd recommend making your own bounces anyway. Unless you just need a quick and dirty solution and don't have much expectations, doing it manually is simpler, and it's not hard to do.

I like to make a first arc, set the apex key to Autoclamped interpolation if it isn't already (use the V shortcut), and the low keys to Vector.
Then I duplicate this arc as many times I want, and I adjust the height of the curve. Scale the apex keys to adjust the timing, and use Free vectors if you really need fine-tuning frame by frame.