# Rigid Bodies giving me hard time

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cache, rigidbody

I’m new to blender. Right now I’m working on a music video clip and I made these music notes (simple models) falling from the sky and hit the ground (simple plane). The notes are active rigid body and the floor is passive rigid body. At first it was all working fine and at some point the simulation started making all kinds of problems. Every time I fixed it something else went wrong. Right now the notes are falling way too fast and doesn’t stick to the floor. I tried going back to older versions of the file where the simulation worked and it does the same. I also deleted the cache folder. Before that the notes didn’t even fall, they just stayed put.
What am I missing??
Sorry for the long post!

You can see the test video (when it was working correctly) here: https://youtu.be/639uZKvQy-M

Comment: This might solve your problem - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109883/object-wont-drop-after-keyframing-animate-physics?noredirect=1#comment196921_109883