# Handlers on Graph Editor

Tags: graph-editor

I have some bezier keyframes on an animation.

The normal behavior is having two handlers (A) with a smooth path on the two sides of the node.

I can "freeze" the movement by zooming and shrinking the second handler, zooming and shrinking. (B)

[image]

**But how can I have two independent handlers?**

[image]

I found some related questions about handlers

[Blender graph editor bezier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/blender-graph-editor-bezier)

But I do not want an "automatic" mode, so I can make a "cartoonish" look.

This one is not even answered.

[Setting bouncing curve in graph editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/setting-bouncing-curve-in-graph-editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have two independent handlers, select the vertice, press V > Free. Is that what you want?

Comment: Tips like this are absolute gems - thanks @moonboots :)